# How to add a user to a MySQL instance on the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-app-engine

I'm trying to follow the [Quick Start WordPress for Google App Engine](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/) guide, but ran into an "Error establishing a database" when trying to run Wordpress locally (see below).

[image]

I'm having some trouble with the following instruction:

"After your Cloud SQL instance is created, go to the **Access Control** section of your instance and click on **Users**. Click **New User** and create a user with the name root and specify a password. Now you can connect to your Cloud SQL instance using 3rd-party tools, which we'll do later."

When I go to the **Instance details** for the instance I created, I don't see any **New User** button, but only a button to change the root password (see below).

[image]

I simply changed the password for the root user. Is this in accordance with the instructions?

Further, how would I modify `wp-config.php` accordingly? I now have the following:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //

if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
    /** The name of the Cloud SQL database for WordPress */
    define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress_db');
    /** Live environment Cloud SQL login and SITE_URL info */
    /** Note that from App Engine, the password is not required, so leave it blank here */
    define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/wordpress-143922:wordpress');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
} else {
    /** The name of the local database for WordPress */
    define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress_db');
    /** Local environment MySQL login info */
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
}
```

where `'password'` is replaced by the password I used to set up MySQL locally. Since I've specified a password on the App Engine, should I also not fill it into the first `DB_PASSWORD` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are editing the `wp-config.php` file inside the `wordpress` directory.  That demo ships with another (sample) version outside the `wordpress` directory, which causes confusion.

Also, you need the server location in the `DB_HOST` section.  For example, if in the US-Central district:

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) && strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
        /** The name of the local database for WordPress */
        define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress_db');
        /** Live environment Cloud SQL login and SITE_URL info */
        /** Note that from App Engine, the password is not required, so leave it blank here */
        define('DB_HOST', ':/cloudsql/wordpress-143922:us-central1:wordpress');
        define('DB_USER', 'root');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password&%^&');
    } else {
        /** The name of the local database for WordPress */
        define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress_db');
        /** Local environment MySQL login info */
        define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
        define('DB_USER', 'root');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password&%^&');
    }
```

Comment: [GAEfan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3524613/gaefan), thanks for your answer. As cloned from the Github repository, the `wordpress` directory is empty; should I download wordpress, put the contents in the `wordpress` directory, and replace the `wp-config.php` in `wordpress` with the (suitably modified) one that comes with the starter project? Or can I simply put only the `wp-config.php` in `wordpress` and nothing else?   **Edit** I see that you've also answered my other question :)  The `wordpress` directory should be full of files and I should try downloading again.